# MVC2 - DropDownListFor complex property - no selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2.0, but apparently this was a problem in MVC 3.0 as well.

Basically if you have a "complex" property name, then `Html.DropDownListFor` does not set any `SelectListItem.Selected = true`.

So this works (where `ViewData.States` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`).

```
<td><%= Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.State, ViewData.States ) %></td>
```

But this does not:

```
<td><%= Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.CaseFields[i].State, ViewData.States ) %></td>
```

I saw [this QA where the answerer correctly explained the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957000/mvc3-html-dropdownlistfor-not-populating-selected-item), however his solution of using `SelectList` as the argument to `DropDownListFor` does not work in my case - I get the exact same result (loads of `<option>` elements but not a single `selected="selected"` attribute).

I'm tempted to reimplement `DropDownListFor`, but if anyone knows a workaround I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reimplementing `DropDownListFor` by copying the source from the MVC project on CodePlex and making a few changes.

The main change I made was to replace the call to `ViewData.Eval` (which in MVC 2 and 3 does not support indexed properties) with `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression().Model`, and it works great.

I also added support for numeric Enum values too, as `DropDownListFor` only binds enum values if you use the string (name) value rather than the numeric value.